# How to edit comments?

Tags: support

I see that some comments have been edited, but on comments I have made there is only a delete button, not an edit button.  How do I edit a comment?

Comment: A related question: is there anywhere to request comments be edited when they make a page render badly because of LaTeX errors? E.g.: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/147016/homotopy-groups-other-than-pi-1-what-are-they-good-for

Answer (score 6):

From [meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work):

> Users may edit their own comments any number of times for five minutes after they are first posted. Edited comments are marked with a little pencil icon, and a mouseover tooltip over that icon will provide a count of how many times the comment was edited, like this:
>
> Moderators can edit any comment at any time. Moderator comment edits are logged and visible to other moderators, but no revision history is kept. Such edits will also show the pencil icon.
>
> In all other situations, comments cannot be edited. However, in lieu of editing, they may be deleted and resubmitted.

Comment: Thanks, Francois.

Comment: Is there a reason your recent posts are CW?